# Next / Prev post link not working wp

Tags: wordpress, loops, hyperlink

Ok so I am having issues with linking to next and previous posts...

Here is my code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...

<div id="project-prev"> <?php previous_post_link('Prev'); ?> </div>
<div id="project-next"> <?php next_post_link('Next'); ?> </div>]

...

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have read places that next/prev posts requires a 'new WP_Query' query, but have had no such luck. There is no next/prev link rendered out on my site, using the above.

As always appreciate solutions and pointers.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried following (according to Wordpress codex)

```
 <?php next_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>'); ?> 
 <?php previous_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>'); ?>
```

In your divs ... :) If you still encouter problems, then just try something like:

```
<?php echo get_previous_posts_link('Prev'); ?>
<?php echo get_next_posts_link('Next'); ?>
```

Should work.

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="project-prev"><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'PREV'); ?></div>
<div id="project-next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'NEXT'); ?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Martina I would like it to have a custom name like 'next' and 'prev' and to display the next post with similar tag e.g. 'projects'

Comment: Searched everywhere, this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**First try and get the next and previous posts.**

```
<?php
$previous_post_url = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false, '', true));
$next_post_url = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false, '', false));
?>
```

**And then create to `<a>` tags and echo out the URLs we set above.**

```
<?php if ( $previous_post_url != get_the_permalink() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $previous_post_url; ?>">Previous Project</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $next_post_url != get_the_permalink() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $next_post_url; ?>">Next Project</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason that could make these links not to show is having the posts set as draft. Only published posts will make the previous and next post links render.